# css - converting from an external style sheet to inline; not sure where some "dropdown" styles go

Tags: html, css, inline, stylesheet

I have a style sheet designed to create a neat menu and it works great. The problem is that I need to move this menu into web pages which require different style elements. **EDIT! When the style sheet is loaded by the new pages, it completely screws them up! Applying the styles to the whole page is a NON-STARTER! That's the whole problem here...**

Since we apparently don't have the ability to "scope" effectively (and serve everyone, right?), or if we do, I didn't discover how yet... and so I figured I'd just move over the styles to the individual elements, the problem is I don't see where some of these styles are supposed to go!

Pointer to a great reference that helps clarify this would be great, or just some comments on where the items go would work, too!

Here's the css - it's reasonably short! And I've removed the ones I already know where go...

```
.dropbtn
{
   display: inline-block;
   color: white;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 8px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn
{
   background-color: #111;
}
li.dropdown
{
   display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content
{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: navy;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a
{
   color: white;
   padding: 8px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-aligh: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover
{
   background-color: blue;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
{
   display: block;
}
```

Here's the original menu - names edited to protect the guilty!

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
   background-color: navy;" >
  <li class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
    <a href="http://example.com/first.html" class="dropbtn">
      First Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://example.com/1st1st.html">1st pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  <li class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
    <a href="http://example.com/second.html" class="dropbtn">
      Second Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://example.com/2nd1st.html">2nd pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  <li class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
    <a href="http://example.com/fourth.html" class="dropbtn">
      Fourth Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://example.com/4th1st.html">4th pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  <li style="float:right" class="dropdown">
    <a href="http://example.com/fifth.html" class="dropbtn">
      Fifth Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://example.com/5th1st.html">5th pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

... I have no idea how to set the styles in-line for things like "hover"!

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: "Completely screws them up" -- How? What does the HTML look like for those pages that is so different from the page that it currently works on?

Comment: @Jhecht ... In particular, as I note to Alexander below, lists were malformed. They'd be horizontal instead of vertical until the end-of-line was reached, and then a new line was started with the next list element. There were a few other minor screwups.  ... As noted below, I found a solution; put as much as I can into the inline style format - just for the menu, mind you - and remove them from the style sheet, and continue to use both. The more obscure style features I didn't know how to specify otherwise remained in the style sheet. It works!

Comment: I can't particularly say I agree with that solution, but if it works. I'm honestly not understanding why you don't just use different class names for the lists that aren't meant to be horizontally oriented.

Comment: @Jhecht ...Perhaps because nobody came up with that as an answer when before I managed to get this other solution working?! :-) If you want to put it up as an answer, please do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fast solution, put all your CSS inside the HTML not inline but in Style tags and remove the styles from the style sheet file:

```
<style>
  .dropbtn
{
   display: inline-block;
   color: white;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 8px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn
{
   background-color: #111;
}
li.dropdown
{
   display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content
{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: navy;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a
{
   color: white;
   padding: 8px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-aligh: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover
{
   background-color: blue;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
{
   display: block;
}
</style>

<ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
   background-color: navy;" >
  <li class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
    <a href="http://example.com/first.html" class="dropbtn">
      First Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://example.com/1st1st.html">1st pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  <li class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
    <a href="http://example.com/second.html" class="dropbtn">
      Second Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://example.com/2nd1st.html">2nd pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  <li class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
    <a href="http://example.com/fourth.html" class="dropbtn">
      Fourth Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://example.com/4th1st.html">4th pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  <li style="float:right" class="dropdown">
    <a href="http://example.com/fifth.html" class="dropbtn">
      Fifth Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://example.com/5th1st.html">5th pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The other solution that I like to use is Mailchimp CSS Inline tool. It takes your style sheet and puts all the CSS styles inline automatically. You just remove the CSS styles from your stylesheet and then include the style sheet with the remaining css styles as usual. I put your CSS and HTML in there and this is the output. Let me know if any of the two worked.

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
   background-color: navy;">
  <li class="dropdown" style="float: left;display: inline-block;">
    <a href="http://example.com/first.html" class="dropbtn" style="display: inline-block;color: white;text-align: left;padding: 8px 16px;text-decoration: none;">
      First Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;position: absolute;background-color: navy;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">
      <a href="http://example.com/1st1st.html" style="color: white;padding: 8px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;text-aligh: left;">1st pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  <li class="dropdown" style="float: left;display: inline-block;">
    <a href="http://example.com/second.html" class="dropbtn" style="display: inline-block;color: white;text-align: left;padding: 8px 16px;text-decoration: none;">
      Second Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;position: absolute;background-color: navy;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">
      <a href="http://example.com/2nd1st.html" style="color: white;padding: 8px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;text-aligh: left;">2nd pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  <li class="dropdown" style="float: left;display: inline-block;">
    <a href="http://example.com/fourth.html" class="dropbtn" style="display: inline-block;color: white;text-align: left;padding: 8px 16px;text-decoration: none;">
      Fourth Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;position: absolute;background-color: navy;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">
      <a href="http://example.com/4th1st.html" style="color: white;padding: 8px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;text-aligh: left;">4th pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  <li style="float: right;display: inline-block;" class="dropdown">
    <a href="http://example.com/fifth.html" class="dropbtn" style="display: inline-block;color: white;text-align: left;padding: 8px 16px;text-decoration: none;">
      Fifth Pulldown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;position: absolute;background-color: navy;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">
      <a href="http://example.com/5th1st.html" style="color: white;padding: 8px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;text-aligh: left;">5th pulldown, 1st item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can try the CSS Inline tool here: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Comment: ...Doesn't your first solution corrupt all the OTHER HTML on the page with the style used in the menu?! I'm pretty sure that's the whole problem! I already just tried including the style sheet and it screwed up the first page I looked at - and the next seven! But if you're saying this would be different, THAT is information I could use!

Comment: OH WAIT, do you mean just including those style sheet items that don't otherwise have a place to be included inline? Hmmm...

Comment: It should work. If you could add a link or image to your site so that I can take a look at what you are trying to archive. If I get you right, you want different CSS styles based on the site you are currently viewing. The way I would do that is to give each page distinctive class and id names so that I can style each page differently. For example, div class=""firstPageClass", div class="secondPageClass". Now the same div can have two styling options. That is how you could scope CSS.

Comment: Not quite. The site doesn't want its data here but this isn't about "different styles based on the site", it's based on the fact that the styles used in the menu system they like COMPLETELY TRASH page layout regarding lists since they flip from vertical to horizontal. ... I just tried your idea and it only partially worked; the menu looks great, but on this one page list elements are appended horizontally until they fill a line and THEN we get a new list element on a new vertically spaced line. That's NOT OK... Your idea about "each page differently"; is off-base.

Comment: ...Actually, I'm not sure I just tried your scheme because you didn't confirm what I asked... I just cropped the style sheet a lot, moving the items I know what to put onto the individual elements "inline"... CLOSE!

Comment: OK, now I got it!

If you would be so kind as to EDIT your answer, I'll mark it as correct: The RIGHT thing to do was to move over all the style I could from the css file to become in-line style elements, then remove those elements from the style sheet file - the css file - then include that css file as normal.  That way, they only applied to those things they NEED to apply to! :-) Thanks for the concept, if that's what you intended or not!

Comment: I thought you already removed the css styles from the CSS style sheet after putting them inline. I will edit my answer then. Good that it worked out.

Comment: As I said in the opening of my original question; I didn't know where to put them! I thought it was clear I just removed the reference to the style sheet entirely, then started moving over the styles to become in-line and had some left-over I didn't know what to do with - didn't (and still don't) know how to specify them in the in-line format. Now, I have an edited style sheet with some styles applied in-line and the rest in the style sheet.

Comment: That must be one hell of an nasty site.

Comment: ...Not really, no, they are just novices and didn't have a plan. Fairly typical in that regard. The menu looks nice, I see why they want to keep it. In fact a new question has arisen: how to load the menu "on the fly" in the future because they think it may change and want all their old pages to have the new format - whenever, IF ever, there is one.

Comment: Well if you post that separately maybe we can help.

Answer (score 2):

What you do is you put an ID on the `<ul>` for your menu(s). Do something like `id="awesomemenu_1"` (since IDs need to be unique, if you want to include more than one menu on the page, you'll have to have a differentiator).

Then, in your CSS-file, you prefix all those rules you already have with `[id^=awesomemenu_]` - so `[id^=awesomemenu_] .dropbtn` and so forth. *However* you will need to override general rules in the existing CSS - for instance, it sounds like some other rules are setting either horisontal or vertical styles for your `<ul>` / `<li>`-items, which doesn't work with your menu. That is easily overriden, though.